# What is the maximum weight loading from a drywall screw stud?

Tags: drywall

what sort of weight can I hang off a drywall screw stud?

Comment: *Drywall screw stud?* Also, static weight or dynamic weight? Also Shear forces (down) or tension forces (outward)?

Comment: It also depends what you're attaching and how it is attached. I would only try trust about 30lbs per screw for normal applications.  The pull out force is somewhere around 160lbs but shear strength is alot less. The more the screw is out of wall the worse it gets.  I could break a 3" screw sticking 1.5" from wall by hand.

Comment: Anything that moves or is pulled on,poses a safety risk or of any real value I would not use a drywall screw.

Comment: Bib, thanks it is static weight with tension force.

Comment: Its not a duplicate.  That question was about drywall anchors this is about drywall screw in stud.

Answer (score 0):

First there is no easy way to answer the question.  It is a physics question that requires:

- length of area of screw inserted into framing
- the ability of framing to hold screw (this would involve a very complex set of equations)
- angle of the screw
- materials and manufacturing process of the screw (even with drywall screws there is a spectrum of quality)
- temperature (not a huge factor but still)
- the verticality of the load
- time (the ability to hold an object will dissipate as screw becomes loose when loads get to more than 1/3 to 1/2 of its capacity)

[Here are some numbers for wood screws into 2x4 framing](http://www.awc.org/pdf/NDSCommentaryCompressed/Part11WoodScrewspp133to139.pdf).

Just to give a round number I would be comfortable saying 100lbs for a drywall screw drilled 1.5 inches into a premium southern pine 2x4.  Just into drywall... 2lbs.

Comment: Would you hang your flat screen tv on the wall with 1 drywall screw? Will it old 100lb? Yes.Under certain situations. but is that a working load? No

Comment: @JustinK - No way I would.  Should have added time in there.  Will edit.  Also if just one screw you are introducing a lot more pull and lateral force which will eventually cause movement in the screw.

Answer (score 0):

How much weight a drywall screw will vary based on a number of different factors including the  size and design of the screw and the materials used to make it. These can vary by manufacturer. The type of wood and the type of load are also a factor.

It's possible the manufacturer or your screws has released technical information about the screws you plan to use. Here's an example http://www.trianglefastener.com/pdf/drywall.pdf

Drywall screws are generally not recommended to hold weight such as to hang things off of. They're called drywall screws not hanging-off-of screws. :) They have a thinner shaft and are [more brittle](http://woodgears.ca/joint_strength/drywall_screws.html) than other types of screws.